# wB.Save and wB.Close are not taking into account after the loop

Tags: vba, loops, crash, save

I have a file with several workbooks. I am using this macro (below) to do some changes at each workbook of this file.

```
Sub REPLACE1()
Dim y As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\MYLOCATION\")

For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)
    With wB.Sheets("vlcs")
        For y = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(y, "A") = "" Then
                .Cells(y, "A") = 0
            End If
            If .Cells(y, "O") = "" Then
                .Cells(y, "O") = 0
            End If
            If Left(.Cells(y, "H").Value, 2) = "24" Then
                .Cells(y, "H") = 2359
            End If
        Next y
    End With
    wB.Save
    wB.Close         '<---- Problems are from here
Next fileobj
End Sub
```

Everything works well regarding the loop but, there is a problem with wB.Save and wB.Close.
For each workbooks looped I have the alert "Do you want to save changes", which is not normal since I save and close my looped files. Moreover, if I click YES everything crash. I tried to put DoEvents after wB.Close but nothing has changed. 
Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `wB.Close False`, where False means Don't save changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam, indeed I don't have the alert "Do you want to save changes" anymore. The problem is that, the changes done my loop are not saved..

Comment: Is the problem still there if you step through your code (using F8)? If not - then you have to make sure it is saved before proceeding. If you still can't get it saved, I think you must eliminate other reasons than your code first. Are the files stored in a location you have write access to, etc.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of `wB.Save` & `wB.Close` and replacing them two lines with `wB.Close True`?

Comment: Yes you might be right. I think it is an Excel setting problem since it worked on another computer. But what setting can it be, I don't know.

Comment: @Xabier this way, I have every workbooks opened and when I close them it ask me if I want save the changes. Its a mystery. But thanks for your contribution, it could have work indeed.

Comment: What happens if you open one of the workbooks interactively and close it without changes? And with changes?

Comment: If I close it with changes Excel crash, if I don't it does not crash , but my macro gets useless then

Comment: Then it isn't a VBA problem anymore. There can be a few reasons why it crash, but this isn't the place to solve that. Your last hope (in the realm of VBA) is to use SaveAs and store it in a parallel folder.

Comment: @IlvarNourtan, just a thought,... have you tried defining y as Long instead of Integer?